# Google App Engine Python Upload Error

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine

I am not sure why I am getting this error when trying to deploy my Python API via the Google App Engine Launcher.

Any Ideas what it is that I have going on here? Below is the error and my associated App.yaml file.

```
appcfg.py: error: Error parsing C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\Workspace\Imhotep\Imhotep\app.yaml: while parsing a block mapping
      in "C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\Workspace\Imhotep\Imhotep\app.yaml", line 1, column 1
    expected <block end>, but found '<block sequence start>'
      in "C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\Workspace\Imhotep\Imhotep\app.yaml", line 14, column 2.
    2013-11-17 20:37:33 (Process exited with code 2)





application: <IHAVEMYAPPIDHERE - PROVIDED BY GAE>
version: 1
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:
 # Static assets
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images


 # Endpoints handler
 - url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: imhotep_api.APPLICATION
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whitespace is important in yaml files.

It looks like there's an extra space in front of the 2nd url line.

I'm not sure if the extra blank lines cause problems.

Oh, and if you're having problems deploying, it probably means you should have tested locally first.

Comment: It was due to whitespace. I fixed it and it looks like it is working now. I am also testing the API locally.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that in all of my app.yaml files threadsafe is set to 'yes' and not 'true'. Also, possibly more importantly, I have never seen the '.APPLICATION' extension in a .yaml file. In all of mine, and all the .yaml's I have seen it is '.app'.

Ex: script: imhotep_api.app

sorry if that's of no help.